# How to place 2 absolute positioned div one after another

Tags: html, css

I'm using 2 divs to hold background images for web page,both divs are absolutely positioned, both divs have background images assigned,but when rendered on web page the divs are overlapping. the images render as overlapped images.

How to display absolute divs one after another.

Code:

```css
.body-bg-image {
  width: 28%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(https://i.pinimg.com/originals/9b/20/74/9b207482ee0f226be45799eca2f3b45f.jpg) top center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0px auto;
  opacity: 0.6;
  z-index: -1;
}

.body-bg-bottom {
  width: 28%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(https://i.pinimg.com/originals/9b/20/74/9b207482ee0f226be45799eca2f3b45f.jpg) top center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  margin: 0px auto;
  opacity: 0.6;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="body-bg-image"></div>
<div class="body-bg-bottom"></div>

<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
</div>

</html>
```

Here is the fiddle what i'm trying to achieve.
https://jsfiddle.net/gm9rd563/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure about your expected result, but maybe  `.body-bg-bottom { top: 100%; }` achieves your desired result?

Without adding a `top` position, the element is rendered where it would be rendered if it didn't have `position: absolute` with regard to its vertical position. As the only element preceding it has `position: absolute;` as well, the predecessing element doesn't influence the position of `div.body-bg-bottom`, resulting in both `div` elements being rendered exactly on top of each other.

Also, both `div` elements have a number of declarations in common, which allows for more concise CSS:

```css
.body-bg-image,
.body-bg-bottom {
  background: top center / cover no-repeat url(https://i.pinimg.com/originals/9b/20/74/9b207482ee0f226be45799eca2f3b45f.jpg);
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  opacity: 0.6;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 28%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.body-bg-bottom {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="body-bg-image"></div>
<div class="body-bg-bottom"></div>

<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus, nihil assumenda quaerat soluta incidunt adipisci modi nisi libero sequi! Tenetur praesentium voluptatem rem, est ea ut a accusantium odit culpa?</p>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: Whatever are all these paragraphs for ? At the border of vandalism …

Comment: These paragraphs are from OP's external code representation on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gm9rd563/). They serve as content placeholder so you can see how things play out on a real page with content.

Comment: Hm. I think they are rather disturbing. One can clearly see the images are overlapping (or not) without the text. At least, 10 lines would be enough I think.

Comment: OP chose to demonstrate their issue using the content placeholder paragraphs, so why would I remove those?

Comment: Because it makes the answer look messy and long …

Answer (score 0):

You could put the two background DIVs inside an overall background-container DIV, remove `position: absolute;` from the two child DIVs and make the container DIV `position: absolute;` instead.

```
<div class="body-bg-container">
    <div class="body-bg-image"></div>
    <div class="body-bg-bottom"></div>
</div>
```